# In Emacs how can I search a directory and all subdirectories for a filename?

Tags: emacs

In Emacs how can I search a directory and all subdirectories for a filename?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `M-x find-name-dired`. It will ask for a directory and a wildcard pattern, so you can enter something like `*thing*` and have all files with "thing" in the name listed in a dired buffer.

More here: http://emacswiki.org/emacs/RecursiveGrep (along with a snippet that lets you skip writing out the stars too).

Answer (score 4):

In dired, you can list all the subdirectories of the visited directory by moving to the first line and pressing `C-u l` and adding the [`R` switch](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Subdir-Switches.html). You can then search the file name in the buffer, or mark files based on a regexp with `% m`.

On Linux, or Windows with Cygwin utilities, or other unix-like system with GNU find, a quick-and-dirty hack is `M-x grep-find`, and edit the command line to contain just the `find` part with a suitable format:

```
find -type f -name '*.foo' -printf '%p:0:\n'
```

On any system that has unix tools available, you can run the `find` command with `M-! find`. In the output buffer, you can use `M-x ffap` to visit the chosen file. You can also [set up dired-x](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/dired-x.html#Optional-Installation-File-At-Point) so that `C-u C-x C-f` can be used instead of `M-x ffap`.

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays, this can be done using the function `directory-files-recursively`.

Answer (score 2):

In emacs 23, try  `M-x find-dired`

Answer (score 1):

You can open: `*/foo.bar` for finding any files named foo.bar in a direct subdirectory of the current one, or `**/foo.bar`for finding any files named foo.bar recursively in subdirectories of the current one.

Comment: This doesn't work for me -- I suspect it requires some library that isn't loaded by default.

Comment: It work here with stock Emacs (with emacs -q --no-site-file), I do know that this was not available with older Emacs, and it conflict with ido.

Comment: You're right; it works for me, too.  I never noticed that!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [consult](https://github.com/minad/consult), there is the very convenient `consult-find`:
[image]

It updates the minibuffer as you type, and then you can just select the item you want and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to open the file in a buffer.[image]

I'm also using [vertico](https://github.com/minad/vertico) for the vertical minibuffer display and [marginalia](https://github.com/minad/marginalia) for the in-minibuffer function annotations seen in the first screenshot.